# Access objects instantiated by sibling control

Tags: c#, winforms, class

Being fairly new to C# and OOP I'm having some newbie problems with scope and access, one of them being this: When the main form loads an instance of the class Doc is created and the constructor opens a Word document and creates a list of all the images in the document. The first image in the list is displayed in a picturebox, like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Doc {
        public List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
        public Doc(string path) {
            // Open Word document, create list of images
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Doc doc = new Doc("C:\\lorem_ipsum.doc");
        pictureBox1.Image = doc.images[0];
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        pictureBox1.Image =  doc.images[numericUpDown1.Value];
    }
}
```

There is also a numericUpDown control which should be used to display different images, and that's where the problem is. The last block of code in the example above doesn't work, but I hope it illustrates what I want to do.

What would be a best practice solution to this problem (and similar ones where one control should be able to access objects created by other controls)? I have also tried to solve it by creating a method for the Doc class but had problems accessing the picturebox from there instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you created `doc` as a local variable. You need a member variable within the scope of the class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private Doc _doc; // Add this line

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Doc {
        public List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
        public Doc(string path) {
            // Open Word document, create list of images
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        _doc = new Doc("C:\\lorem_ipsum.doc");
        pictureBox1.Image = _doc.images[0];
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        pictureBox1.Image =  _doc.images[numericUpDown1.Value];
    }
}
```

**A little about scope**

```
public class MyClass
{
    // myMemberVariable is declared inside class, but outside
    // a function. Therefore, it can be accessed from anywhere
    // inside the class.
    int myMemberVariable;

    public void MyFunction()
    {
        // myLocalVariable is declared inside a function. Therefore,
        // it can be accessed only inside this function and nowhere
        // else.
        int myLocalVariable;

        for (int x=0;x<10;x++)
        {
            // anotherLocalVariable is declared inside a for loop. Therefore,
            // this variable can only be used inside this for loop and
            // no where else.
            int anotherLocalVariable;
        }
    }
}
```

Think of the braces as scope delimiters. Variables you create can only be used within the opening and closing braces and never outside. The only "partial" exception to this would be `static` variables.

Comment: Ah, that was simple. Thanks to everyone (except the downvoter). Is this approach reasonably close to best practice or is it just what happened to be the easiest way to get my crappy design to work? :)

Comment: @linurb - This isn't a "best practice". This is how scope in C# works.

Comment: @linurb I do want to point out that one could argue that the `Doc` (and `Form1`) class itself is poorly named and probably should not be a nested class in the `Form1` class. If you want/need a code review, you should [check out the code review StackExchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Anthony Thanks, nesting and general design are the kinds of things I had in mind - what to put into the class and what to do outside of it etc. I'll probably learn about that too as I go along, but I suppose it's a good idea not to develop too many bad habits before I get there. The code review site will come surely be of help here.

Answer (score 1):

Just make `doc` a private field of `Form1`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private Doc doc;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Doc {
        public List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
        public Doc(string path) {
            // Open Word document, create list of images
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        doc = new Doc("C:\\lorem_ipsum.doc");
        pictureBox1.Image = dok.images[0];
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        pictureBox1.Image =  doc.images[numericUpDown1.Value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `doc` you have there is a local variable, i.e. it's local to `Form1_Load`. That means it only exists inside that method. What you want is a member field, defined on the `Form1` class itself. That will stick around as long as the form exists:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Doc m_Doc;

    ....

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_Doc = new Doc("C:\\lorem_ipsum.doc");
        pictureBox1.Image = m_Doc.images[0];
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = m_Doc.images[numericUpDown1.Value];
    }
}
```

Now `m_Doc` will be accessible to anything in the class (and to nested classes as well), but nothing else, since it's `private`.

I've also chosen to add a `m_` suffix. It is not necessary and people will argue about what convention is best all night long, but that's what I prefer!